# pandas unique() method do not show all the unique values of a column

Tags: pandas, unique

Hi I am trying to use pandas unique() method to get all the unique values of a column but the column has so many unique values that after showing few unique values, it shows three dots like this:

```
array(['NON-Stemi', 'absolute Arrhythmie', 'None', ..., 'V3-v6',
   'Arrhythm., ST-Strecke nicht beurteilbar', 'VORWANDINFAKT'],
    dtype=object)
```

How to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use DataFrame.drop_duplicates() instead of pandas unique()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Naidu    drop_duplicates will drop the duplicate values in the column but i want  to get all the unique values of the column not drop it.

Comment: unique_values = list(dataframe.unique())